# new child of parent's constructor with dependency not working

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, factory

I have an issue with a class A instanciated via a factory and a class B extends class A.

Here some example code :

```
class ClassAFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $one= $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.one');
        $two= $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.two');
        $three= $serviceLocator->get('Application\Service\three');
        return new ClassA($one, $two, $three);
    }
}

class ClassA implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    private $one;
    private $two;
    private $three;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $one, ObjectManager $two, Three $three)
    {
        $this->one= $one;
        $this->two= $two;
        $this->three= $three;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    // Some usefull code
}
```

How can i call class B without passing dependancies, how can i retrieve the instance of class A done by the factory when i did : new ClassB(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that directly. You *can* create a service factory for `ClassB` too, but that involves code duplication:

```
class ClassBFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $one   = $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.one');
        $two   = $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.two');
        $three = $serviceLocator->get('Application\Service\three');
        return new ClassB($one, $two, $three);
    }
}
```

But, your class `ClassA` (and therefore `ClassB`) is service-locator aware already, so you can lazy-load your entity managers; this way, you don't need service factories at all:

```
class ClassA implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    private $one;
    private $two;
    private $three;

    private function getOne()
    {
        if (!$this->one) {
            $this->one = $this->getServiceLocator()
                              ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.one');
        }

        return $this->one;
    }

    private function getTwo()
    {
        if (!$this->two) {
            $this->two = $this->getServiceLocator()
                              ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.two');
        }

        return $this->two;
    }

    public function __construct(Three $three)
    {
        $this->three = $three;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    // Some usefull code
}
```

Just update your code in `ClassA` to access your entity managers with `$this->getOne()` & `$this->getTwo()` instead of `$this->one` & `$this->two`.

After that, you can access `ClassA` & `ClassB` just like others:

```
$a = $serviceLocator->get('Namespace\...\ClassA');
$b = $serviceLocator->get('Namespace\...\ClassB');
```